# get member of global object using string

Tags: javascript

I have a global javascript object which has submembers and I need to access it's members by a provided string. The object looks like:

```
var student = {
    0 : {
        name : "a",
        level : 2
      }
    1 : {
        name : "b",
        level : 3
      }
      ...
```

and I want to access it like when using the top level as a string:

```
   this["student[0]['name']"];   // returns undefined
   window["student[0]['name']"]; // same here
```

but this is only working for the variable names:

```
  this["student"];    // returns the student object
  window["student"];  // same
```

can this be done? Or what is the correct way to get the member defined with

```
var accesskey = 'student[0]["name"]';
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is a very confusing idea to give a number as key. If you do not have any gaps, instead use `var student = [ {name : "a", level : 2}, {name : "b", level : 3} ...]`

Comment: That's just a pseudocode I gave there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically only have two choices, assuming the format of `accessKey` is fixed and cannot be changed:

1. Parsing the string yourself and then handling using the relevant key for each level. That string is fairly easy to split:

   ```
   var parts = accessKey.split(/[\[\]"]+/);
   ```

   (Be sure to ignore `""` as the first or last entry in `parts`.)
2. Use `eval`:

   ```
   var val = eval(accessKey);
   ```

   But only do that if **you are in absolute control of that string**. Never use `eval` on input you don't control, and avoid using it even when you do control the input.

Comment: Thanks. I just wonder if there's another way without splits and evals available.

Comment: @TahaPaksu: No, it's going to be parsing (and splitting is one way of doing that) or `eval`.

Comment: what's wrong with using eval on input you don't control; wouldn't F12 be an easier way to hack yourself?

Comment: @dandavis: It totally depends on where the input is coming from. For instance, if it's coming from the user and you only use it in *their* browser, well, that may be vaguely okay although in general you want to avoid letting the user trip themselves up (using F12 is clearly outside normal use of a site). But the real danger is using one user's input in *another* user's browser.

Comment: i agree with that, i just didn't see how a "var=" could come from another user in this instance...

Comment: @dandavis: I assumed that was a standin. :-)

Comment: i try to stick up for eval because it's powerful and unfairly slammed a lot. it can be made safe in strict mode (unlike Function), and i've seen folks warn against eval in one breath and then recommend jsonp in the next. Often there are better ways of accomplishing something, but eval is the only way here if student were not a member of window, and a simple way even if it is...

Comment: @dandavis: Hey, at least I didn't just cough up the standard "`eval` is evil" hairball. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I really wouldn't recommend trying to access a value using a key in the form `"student[0]['name']"` because that will require `eval()`ing. Instead, you could have a key in the form
`['student', 0, 'name']`. In this form you can use the key to access any nested portion of the a structure.

You will need a function which can resolve that key to the nested value first:

```
function get_nested_value(key, source) {
    var sub = source || window;
    for (var i = 0; i < key.length; ++i) {
        sub = sub[key[i]];
    }
    return sub;
}
```

The value can then be gotten with:

```
var key = ['student', 0, 'name'];
var value = get_nested_value(key);
```

If you're really set on using the key strictly as a string in the form `'student[0]["name"]'`, you're going to have to take the `eval()` approach given by [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22100854/369450), however `eval()` is generally not safe.

Comment: I know that but that doesn't answer the question. the string I have is `'student[0]["name"]'`. I wonder if that can be achieved without splitting.

Comment: @TahaPaksu: What do you want to happen if the string is `alert(42)`?

Comment: That's irrevelant. I don't want to use eval.

Comment: @dandavis It's starting at `window[key[0]]` which is `window['student']` because `key[0] == 'student'`.

Comment: ok, nevermind. sorry. i obviously need more coffee... ;)  this is good.

Comment: @dandavis Try running `for (var i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {console.log(i);}` in the console.

Comment: one thing to consider is readability. to uncaffeinated me, and someone else who "upped" my comment, it LOOKS wrong. You can call us dumb, which may be true, but an answer that is readable to idiots is better than one that's confusing. Given that, and in the context of an answer, i think KISS is not bad advice considering both options work...

Comment: @dandavis I'm still not sure what looks wrong. It's equivalent to the classic recursive function but implemented as a loop.

Comment: the "++i" looks wrong, when "i++" is universally recognized. I know that for is more like until than while, but we don't just code for machines, we code for people as well. Not all of those people are as wise as you, and so it wouldn't hurt to use a more recognizable form...

Comment: @dandavis I see what you mean now. I usually prefer `++i` because then I don't have to mentally think if `i` will be different from what's being assigned to it. In the *increment* portion of a for-loop they are effectively the same, but people do tend to do `i++` instead of `++i`.